# Feeling exhausted after swimming

Tags: swimming, energy, tiredness

I've been swimming for 5 hours straight. Now I'm out of the pool and I've been out for an hour. I have homework but I'm extremely sleepy. I've read why this is caused, mainly:

- The cold temperature in the pool
- The amount of energy needed to swim.
- etc.

But even after all my research no one said how I can feel energetic again. What can I do to feel better after swimming? I don't drink coffee.

Comment: A colder pool will simply make you burn more calories. Since it is at a pool, next time eat enough while working out to replace some of the calories. You are likely exhausted after because your blood sugar can't get back up... it is being recruited to restore your brain muscles and organs as it is slowly converted from fat and muscles.

Comment: Swimming is pretty hard exercise; it's probably just exhaustion. It's also possible that on getting out of the pool you got a little cold - this can enhance tiredeness. There may be some minor additional effect: I feel more tired after an hour's swimming than an hour's run even for similar calorie estimates, but this could say more about calorie exertion.

Answer (score 4):

5 hours of any workout would exhaust you for the rest of the day. Now regarding what to do next? Eat food to help you with your calorie needs and if possible, take a nap. That may not remove all the exhaustion, but would give you enough energy to get other things done.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head. how about a protein shake post workout, I also supplement L-Glutamine after working out and before bed. This amino acid helps with protein synthesis and recovery it also helps your mental state as it can cross the Blood Brain Barrier.

Comment: Probably true; but sometimes I swim for an hour and I come back exhausted. Normal?